# afterDelay:0 is there a better solution?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsobject, catransaction

#### • My general goal

My goal is

1. to load some data in a view-based Table View and perform some operations (for the display of the Table View)
2. at the end of loading to scroll to the top of the Table View.

#### • Some more details

During the loading, a lot of actions are performed. More precisely, the Table View is view-based and in each row, there is a Text View whose content is bound to some property. 
The delegate method `- (void)textDidChange:` is implemented (to enlarge the Text View if necessary). 
I have also subclassed `NSTextView` and overwritten the method `- (void)setString:` for the same purpose.

So, when the text is loaded to the rows of the Table View, a lot of actions are performed.

#### • The code

My code works with `afterDelay:0` (scrolling to the top happens) but not without.

```
// works
- (void)updateTheController
{
    [super updateTheController] ;
    self.theCollectionView.representedObject = self.representedObject ;
    [self.theCollectionView performSelector:@selector(goToTop) 
                                 withObject:nil 
                                 afterDelay:0] ;
}
```

but

```
// does not work
- (void)updateTheController
{
    [super updateTheController] ;
    self.theCollectionView.representedObject = self.representedObject ;
    [self.theCollectionView goToTop] ;
}
```

#### • My question

I am wondering if there is a better solution or an explanation. I remember something with `CATransaction` but I don't know if it will work here, and I don't remember which method to call (and why), `[CATransaction commit]`, `[CATransaction commit]`?

My question could be: **By what can I replace `afterDelay:0` and why do I need it?**

Thanks!!

Comment: IMHO with afterDelay: the command is executed after the current runloop finishes. Only then the view is filled and top can be reached.

Comment: @Volker Yes it might be related to the run loop. This notion of runloop is very unclear for me. I was, in a way, looking for some instruction like `doThisAfterRunloopHasFinished:`

Comment: using afterDelay is exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: I feel `afterDelay:0` is not beautiful :( But, yes, it works.

Comment: @Volker You can make an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you experience has to do how commands are performed and results especially regarding KVO and such are available after the current runloop finishes. In your case the dot-notation of `self.theCollectionView.representedObject = self.representedObject ;` hides a KVO call of `setRepresentedObject:` which automatically gets enclosed in `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` calls. That maybe explains better, why the new representedObject and thus the new view contents isn't available at the moment you run the command but only after the runloop finishes (explanation is more complex!).

Thus with `afterDelay:` the command is executed after the current runloop finishes and only then the view is filled and top can be reached. This sometimes can be annoying since it seems to break the logical flow. Yet, it is absolutely valid.

Comment: I think it is more that `[super updateTheController] ;` triggers some `delegate` methods (like `textDidChange`...)

Comment: NO: you're right, I overwrote the `setRepresentedObject:` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use GCD:

```
- (void)updateTheController
{
    [super updateTheController] ;
    self.theCollectionView.representedObject = self.representedObject;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
        [self.theCollectionView goToTop];
    });
}
```

`[self.theCollectionView goToTop];` will be pushed in queue and performed as soon as posible.

Comment: In a way, it is the opposite I'm trying to achieve: I want the method `goToTop` to be executed but not too quickly and in a proper way.

Comment: @Colas, it will be last in the queue, so it will be performed not too quickly. GCD is the best way perform something asyncronously.

Comment: But the setting of `representedObject` will fire other methods (by notification). Anyway, with your idea, it does not work whereas with `withDelay:` it works :/